# Undefined CodeIgniter variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please, I don't know what am not getting right here...

This is my controller:

```
$result = $this->Career_model->quick_search($gender, $country); // get the data once and then check if data empty or not
if(!empty($result)){ // success
    $data['result'] = $result;
}else{  // fail
    $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found');
}
redirect('pages/search_result',$data);
```

And here is the view:

```
if((isset($result)) && (!empty($result))): // checking if the result is empty
    foreach ($result as $key => $value):
            echo $value->name;
    endforeach;
else:
    echo "No result was found."; // this is the part that gets executed
endif;
```

But once I change my controller to this:

```
$result = $this->Career_model->quick_search($gender, $country); // get the data once and then check if data empty or not

if(!empty($result)){ // success
   $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found'); //this is the part that gets executed, meaning that my result is not empty. 
}else{  // fail
   $data['result'] = $result;
}
redirect('pages/search_result',$data);
```

And the view to this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value):
        echo $value->name;
endforeach;
```

I only end up with an `Undefined variable: result` error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy in the exact, full error? Does it reference a line? If so, please highlight the line in your code snippet.

Comment: The control never goes to the else block because `$result` is not empty. Also, what are you trying to achieve when your (first) code works properly?

Comment: Yes, David it does reference a line... A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: pages/search_result.php

Line Number: 37

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\views\pages\search_result.php
Line: 37
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 73
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\index.php
Line: 286
Function: require_once.

Comment: And here is the foreach block   if((isset($result)) && (!empty($result))):
           foreach ($result as $key => $value):
            echo $value->name;
           endforeach;
          else:
           echo "No result was found.";
          endif;   and this is the controller if(!empty($result)){ // success

         $data['result'] = $result;

     }else{  // fail
 
        $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found');
     }
     $this->load->view('pages/search_result',$data);

Comment: I'm running a search query, Sauhardnc! I want to display the result of the search query. And it obvious that the result array isn't empty but I don't seem to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please add the errors to the question rather than as a comment, so people can help more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me solve the above problem.

This is what I later did...

My new model:

```
function quick_search($country,$gender,$from, $to)
    {
        $this->db->join("about" , "account.ref_id = about.user_id");
        $this->db->like('gender',$gender);
        $this->db->or_like('country',$country);
        $this->db->or_like('age',$from);
        $this->db->where('age <=',$to);
        $query = $this->db->get('account');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

My controller:

$result = $this->Career_model->quick_search($country, $gender, $from, $to); // get the data once and then check if data empty or not
    if(!empty($result)): // success

```
    $data['result'] = $result;

else:  // fail

    $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found');

endif;
$this->load->view('pages/search_result',$data);
```

My new view:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value):
    echo $value['name']." ".$value['gender'].'<br>';
endforeach;
```

Once again, thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Because when success `$data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found')` it doesn't execute `else block` so `$data['resuly']=undefined`

When you will change your controller alter this line `$data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found');` with `$data['result'] =$result`

Comment: I've done that severally! $data['result'] = $result; is the actual if block; while the $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found'); is for the else block. I had to swipe the block stmts to see what was wrong.

Comment: enable your log in codeigniter. goto `config.php $config['log_threshold'] = 1; restart server run your controller` Then check your log file inside `application/logs` directory.

Comment: ERROR - 2020-05-19 15:31:26 --> Severity: Warning --> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\views\pages\search_result.php 37 and here is the line 37 foreach ($result as $key => $value):
            echo $value->name;
           endforeach;